# LESScss if condition when variable is not empty

Tags: html, css, less

I am trying to put font family for a div if the variable is not equal to null.
my less code is

```css
div.content {
  & when (isstring(@contentFont)) {
    font-family: @contentFont;
  }
}
```

the output that I get from css is

```css
div.content when (isstring(@contentFont)) {
   font-family: Abel;
}
```

my problem is, the style is not applying for the div.content, not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that is the output that you get in CSS? When the variable is not null and has a string value, the `when...` part should not be coming in the output at all.

Comment: Your posted LESS seems fine: [working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azoENG). Are you definitely using a version of LESS >= 1.5.0 when that `when` syntax was introduced, and as Harry says are you sure you're correctly compiling the LESS to CSS (and not getting errors) as that is not compiled CSS.

Comment: @Harry yes that's what I am puzzling, i am getting `when` condition in the css

Comment: @shai I am not sure about it. I am using wp-less wordpress plugin of latest version. May be i need to digg in to the files to check less version.

Comment: @shai wp-less using lessphp and its version is 0.4.0. Is this version support `when`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you're using version 0.4.0 of `lessphp` – which doesn't seem to support [the shorthand guard (`when`) syntax](http://lesscss.org/features/#css-guards-feature) that you're trying to use.

It looks like it [does support guards on *mixins*](http://leafo.net/lessphp/docs/#guards), however.

Try splitting your code into a mixin and a usage of this mixin, like this:

```css
/* the mixin */

.fontIfString(@font) when (isstring(@font)) {
    font-family: @font;
}

/* usage */

@contentFont: "hello";

div.content {
    .fontIfString(@contentFont);
}
```